# Why scala-swing Button can be assigned to MainFrame's contents?

Tags: scala, scala-swing

In scala-swing, I can write this simple code:

```
import scala.swing._

object HelloWorld2 extends SimpleSwingApplication {
  val top = new MainFrame()
  top.title = "Hello, World!"
  top.contents = new Button("a")
}
```

it works fine but according to [doc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.12/scala-swing/scala/swing/MainFrame.html#contents:Seq%5Bscala.swing.Component%5D) the type of `contents` in `MainFrame` is `Seq[Component]` whilst the type of Button is `Button`. So why can I write

```
top.contents = new Button("a")
```

without error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the following two method signatures as per API [docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.12/scala-swing/scala/swing/MainFrame.html#contents_=(c:scala.swing.Component):Unit)

```
def contents: Seq[Component]
def contents_=(c: Component): Unit
```

The assignment syntax

```
top.contents = new Button("a")
```

actually makes use of mutator `_=` method

```
def contents_=(c: Component): Unit
```

as explained by [Accessors/Mutators](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html#accessorsmutators)

> For mutators, the name of the method should be the name of the
> property with “_=” appended. As long as a corresponding accessor with
> that particular property name is defined on the enclosing type, this
> convention will enable a call-site mutation syntax which mirrors
> assignment.